# How to inset dummy data in a SQL Server SELECT statement based on table columns

Tags: sql-server, tableau-desktop

I use a BI tool (Tableau) that has visual problems for my clients when certain filters are applied. Reason why is that some categorical values disappear if there is no data for them under these filters selection. The client needs that all combinations are present at all times.

In order to avoid I am trying to inject dummy values that prevents the filtering from happening:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE_A
UNION
SELECT Null AS FIRST_COLUMN, Null AS SECOND_COLUMN, 'Peter' AS THIRD_COLUMN
UNION
SELECT Null AS FIRST_COLUMN, Null AS SECOND_COLUMN, 'Michael' AS THIRD_COLUMN
UNION
SELECT Null AS FIRST_COLUMN, Null AS SECOND_COLUMN, 'James' AS THIRD_COLUMN
...
```

In my real case I have more than 50 columns and from time to time more columns are going to be added.

I was wondering if there is a way in that I can set the values for the columns I am interested in and Null for everything else without the need to define every single column like in the example I provide.

I only have **read** permissions on the table

Comment: Not in SQL, no. A `UNION (ALL)` must have the same definition in each of the queries you are unioning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved my problem using Python to achieve it (detailed below):

First let me detail the problem a little more with an example table

| Student | Sport | Score |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Mark | Football | 50 |
| Mark | Golf | 20 |
| Mark | Basketball | 70 |
| Peter | Golf | 30 |
| Peter | Basketball | 50 |

In Tableau if you filter by sport and select Football will make Peter dissapear from the map since there is no row in the datasource combining Peter and Football, so resulting table after filtering will be this:

| Student | Sport | Score |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Mark | Football | 50 |

But customer expects this:

| Student | Sport | Score |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Mark | Football | 50 |
| Peter | Football | 0 |

So even if Sport its not in the visualization the effect of filtering by Football makes Peter dissapear.

For my solution I take the data from a MSSQL Server put it inside a pandas dataframe. Then I use the following function:

```
import pandas as pd

def dummyGenerator(df: pd.DataFrame, distinct_fields: list, combined_fields: list, filter_selection: dict = {}):
    """
    dummyGenerator takes a pandas DataFrame and generates dummy values based on arguments         
    
    Args:
        df (pandas DataFrame) : Source data to input
        distinct_fields (list): Values to take as a distinct chunk. It will take the combinations present ONLY in the datasource of this fields
        combined_fields (list): Name of destination datasource
        filter_selection (dict): filter for specific values Example: {"field A": ["value1", "value2"], "field B": ["value1", "value2"]}

    Returns:
        resulting dataframe 

    """  
    
    #Distinct: Fields in which we want to take the default combinations available in original datasource
    distinct = df[distinct_fields].drop_duplicates().reset_index(drop=True)

    for field in filter_selection:
        distinct = distinct[distinct[field].isin(filter_selection[field])].reset_index(drop=True)

    #Get combinations combine all possibilities 
    combinations = []

    for field in combined_fields:
        combinations.append(df[field].unique())

    
    combined_df = pd.DataFrame(list(product(*combinations)), columns=combined_fields)

    result_df = pd.DataFrame()

    for column in df.columns:
        if column not in combined_df.columns:
            result_df[column] = None
        else:
            result_df[column] = combined_df[column]


    result = distinct.merge(result_df, how="cross", suffixes= ["", "_y"])

    return result[df.columns.to_list()]
```

After that I concat the data to the original data source and then I refresh **an existent** Tableau's datasource with the following script (Note that tableau version refrence your Tableaus's desktop folder Example: 2022.1":

```
def to_Tableau_DataSource(df: pd.DataFrame, project: str, datasource: str, tableau_version: str, site: str, server: str):
    """
    to_Tableau_DataSource takes a pandas DataFrame query and uses it to refresh a Tableau DataSource 
        
    It also requires an enviromental variable named ASRA containing the username and password in the format <user>@email.com:<password>

    Args:
        df (pandas DataFrame) : Source data to input
        project (str): Name of destination project
        datasource (str): Name of destination datasource
        tableau_version (str): Tableau Desktop version of hosting computer

    Returns:
        Nothing 

    """  
        
    home = str(Path.home()) + "\\Downloads\\"

    connection_string = os.getenv("ASRA") 

    u, p = connection_string.split(":")

    
    si = site
    s= server       

    filename = home + "output.xlsx"
    print(filename)
    df.to_excel(filename, index = False)

    filename.replace("/","\\")

    os.chdir(f"C:\\Program Files\\Tableau\\Tableau {tableau_version}\\bin\\")
    os.system(f'tableau refreshextract --server {s} --username {u} --password {p} --project "{project}" --site {si} --datasource "{datasource}" --original-file "{filename}"')
    os.remove(filename)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can create a calculated field in tableau to populate a column.

```
IFNULL([FIRST_COLUMN], 'Peter')
```

This will replace any null values with the string *Peter*, otherwise it will return the data that is in [FIRST_COLUMN]. Alternatively you could replace the string *Peter* with a string of a blank space (' ').

***Due note the above solution is bad practice.*** This sounds more like a dynamic filtering problem within Dashboard Actions or that you may have your filters set to 'only relevant values'.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, however that not solves the issue because it is not that there is a Null there is **no data** for the filter applied. If there is no row for the combination of filters there is no possibility for a formula